# Как заменить $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] на IP клиента в PHP за двумя Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, docker

На сервере есть два `nginx`: *внешний*, он доступен из интернета, и *внутренний*, он запущен в контейнере `docker`.

*Внешний* `nginx` проксирует запрос во *внутренний*, настраивается вручную. Пример конфигурации:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.site.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.13;
        include proxy_params;
    }
}
```

*Внутренний* `nginx` проксирует запрос в другой docker контейнер с `php-fpm`. Настраивается автоматически при деплое. Пример конфигурации:

```
upstream backend {
    server php:9000;
    server spare:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name test.site.ru;

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass backend;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/web$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /srv/web;
        internal;
    }
}
```

В итоге в PHP мы имеем следующее:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] => http
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] => тут мой IP
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] => тут тоже мой IP
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] => 192.168.10.13
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] => 192.168.10.1
```

Очень хочется, чтобы и *внутренний* `nginx` и `php` не думали про то, что есть ещё какой *внешний* `nginx`, и чтобы `nginx` в логах имел реальные IP адреса, и чтобы в `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` был мой IP, а не IP-адрес Gateway из подсети docker. Как это сделать?

Я знаю про существование модуля [ngx_http_realip_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) для `nginx`, но на этом мои знания заканчиваются, и я не знаю как его установить внутрь контейнера docker в `nginx:alpine`. Быть может есть ещё какие-то варианты решения?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/837915/forwarding-real-remote-ip-to-proxied-server-with-nginx нэ?

Comment: @strangeqargo в документации nginx сказано, что модуль realip "по умолчанию этот модуль не собирается"

Comment: прошу прощения, модуль оказывается включён в образе `nginx:alpine`. нужно было попробовать, не смотря на то что в документации написано. глупо как-то получилось =( Добавил в location следующее `set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8; set_real_ip_from 172.16.0.0/12; set_real_ip_from 192.168.0.0/16; real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;` и всё заработало как надо.